# How to fill multiple input fields from one a HREF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

**update**

I need to be able to reference the XML from my actual XML document, i dont want it just var'd into jQuery...

How do i get the following behaviour to occur...

Searching the label input searches for both label and value, however, only omits results from each to their respective input field so typing Alabama shows Alabama - AL but only gives me Alabama in state and AL in value

also using

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "states.xml", // change to full path of file on server
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml,
        complete: setupAC,
        failure: function(data) {
            alert("XML File could not be found");
            }
    });
```

instead of the var myXML

```
 var myXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><states><state label=Alabama value=AL country="US"><state label=Alaska value=AK country="US"></states>';
$(document).ready(function() {
        var myArrLabel = [];
        var myArrValue = [];
        var myArrCountry = [];

        function parseXml(xml){
            $(xml).find("state").each(function(){
                var a1=[], a2=[], a3=[];
                a1.push($(this).attr("label"));
                a2.push($(this).attr("value"));
                a3.push($(this).attr("country"));
                $.each(a1, function(i, el){
                    if($.inArray(el, myArrLabel) === -1) myArrLabel.push(el);
                });
                $.each(a2, function(i, el){
                    if($.inArray(el, myArrValue) === -1) myArrValue.push(el);
                });
                $.each(a3, function(i, el){
                    if($.inArray(el, myArrCountry) === -1) myArrCountry.push(el);
                });
            }); 
        };
        parseXml( myXml );

        function fillIfUnique(box1, box2, attr1, attr2) {
            var value1 = box1.val();
            var valueItemsForLabel = $(myXml).find('state[' + attr1 + '="' + value1 + '"]');
            if ( valueItemsForLabel.length ) {
                var value2 = valueItemsForLabel.eq(0).attr( attr2 );
                console.log( 'value2: ' + value2 );
                var totalSame = $(myXml).find('state[' + attr1 + '="' + value1 + '"][' + attr2 + '="' + value2 + '"]');
                if( valueItemsForLabel.length==totalSame.length ) {
                    box2.val( value2 );
                } else {
                    box2.val( '' );
                };
            };
        };

        function setupAC() {
            $("input#labelBox").autocomplete({
                source: myArrLabel,
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("input#labelBox").val(ui.item.value);
                    fillIfUnique($('#labelBox'), $('#valueBox'), 'label', 'value');
                    fillIfUnique($('#labelBox'), $('#countryBox'), 'label', 'country');
                }
            });
            $("input#valueBox").autocomplete({
                source: myArrValue,
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("input#valueBox").val(ui.item.value);
                    fillIfUnique($('#valueBox'), $('#labelBox'), 'value', 'label');
                    fillIfUnique($('#valueBox'), $('#countryBox'), 'value', 'country');
                }
            });
            $("input#countryBox").autocomplete({
                source: myArrCountry,
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("input#countryBox").val(ui.item.value);
                    fillIfUnique($('#countryBox'), $('#labelBox'), 'country', 'label');
                    fillIfUnique($('#countryBox'), $('#valueBox'), 'country', 'value');
                }
            });
        };
        setupAC();
    });

    </script>
<form name="search_form" id="searchForm" method="GET">
    <p><label for="labelBox">Label Search</label>
        <input type="text" id="labelBox" name="labelBox" /></p>
    <p><label for="valueBox">Value Search</label> <input type="text" id="valueBox" name="valueBox" /></p>
    <p><label for="countryBox">Country Search</label> <input type="text" id="countryBox" name="countryBox" /></p>

    <p><label></label> <button name="searchKeyword" id="searchKeyword">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a Fiddle, to add more code, to be more specific? Your question is so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

We have to follow this logic: After autocomplete selects value, we have to to check if values for other two fields are unique in their scope. For example, selecting country-code **CA** (xml `value` attribute) has unique `label` **California**, as well as unique `country` **US**. If the values is not unique, than we erase that input value. The checking function name is `fillIfUnique()`, take a look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld8w44vg/1/).

HTML used:

```
<h3>jQuery Autocomplete using XML as Data Source Example</h3>
<form name="search_form" id="searchForm" method="GET">
    <p><label for="labelBox">Label Search</label>
        <input type="text" id="labelBox" name="labelBox" /></p>
    <p><label for="valueBox">Value Search</label> <input type="text" id="valueBox" name="valueBox" /></p>
    <p><label for="countryBox">Country Search</label> <input type="text" id="countryBox" name="countryBox" /></p>

    <p><label></label> <button name="searchKeyword" id="searchKeyword">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArrLabel = [];
    var myArrValue = [];
    var myArrCountry = [];

    function parseXml(xml){
        $(xml).find("state").each(function(){
            var a1=[], a2=[], a3=[];
            a1.push($(this).attr("label"));
            a2.push($(this).attr("value"));
            a3.push($(this).attr("country"));
            $.each(a1, function(i, el){
                if($.inArray(el, myArrLabel) === -1) myArrLabel.push(el);
            });
            $.each(a2, function(i, el){
                if($.inArray(el, myArrValue) === -1) myArrValue.push(el);
            });
            $.each(a3, function(i, el){
                if($.inArray(el, myArrCountry) === -1) myArrCountry.push(el);
            });
        }); 
    };
    parseXml( myXml );

    function fillIfUnique(box1, box2, attr1, attr2) {
        var value1 = box1.val();
        var valueItemsForLabel = $(myXml).find('state[' + attr1 + '="' + value1 + '"]');
        if ( valueItemsForLabel.length ) {
            var value2 = valueItemsForLabel.eq(0).attr( attr2 );
            console.log( 'value2: ' + value2 );
            var totalSame = $(myXml).find('state[' + attr1 + '="' + value1 + '"][' + attr2 + '="' + value2 + '"]');
            if( valueItemsForLabel.length==totalSame.length ) {
                box2.val( value2 );
            } else {
                box2.val( '' );
            };
        };
    };

    function setupAC() {
        $("input#labelBox").autocomplete({
            source: myArrLabel,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("input#labelBox").val(ui.item.value);
                fillIfUnique($('#labelBox'), $('#valueBox'), 'label', 'value');
                fillIfUnique($('#labelBox'), $('#countryBox'), 'label', 'country');
            }
        });
        $("input#valueBox").autocomplete({
            source: myArrValue,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("input#valueBox").val(ui.item.value);
                fillIfUnique($('#valueBox'), $('#labelBox'), 'value', 'label');
                fillIfUnique($('#valueBox'), $('#countryBox'), 'value', 'country');
            }
        });
        $("input#countryBox").autocomplete({
            source: myArrCountry,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("input#countryBox").val(ui.item.value);
                fillIfUnique($('#countryBox'), $('#labelBox'), 'country', 'label');
                fillIfUnique($('#countryBox'), $('#valueBox'), 'country', 'value');
            }
        });
    };
    setupAC();
});
```

Notes: I had to compress and insert XML into script. I removed duplicate entries in arrays.

Comment: How do i link that to an external XML Source?

Comment: also is it possible to search through label and value, show them on the suggested results, but only put their respective values to the input fields?

Comment: Sorry about this, is it possible for the first field to search label but also show its value, so typing wyom will show Wyoming - WY, but only put the onClick into each separate input? also how to link external XML

Comment: I have just hard-coded the xml at top of the Fiddle, you will get it using ajax, same way you did before. For other questions you have: yes, it is possible, you need to try and do it yourself. When you hit the wall next time, than go on and ask another question here on SO. Try to ask one question in a row and try to be more accurate than you did last time.

Comment: When i replaced myXml with $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "states.xml", // change to full path of file on server
   dataType: "xml",
   success: parseXml,
   complete: setupAC,
   failure: function(data) {
    alert("XML File could not be found");
    }
  }); it then stops functioning

Comment: its working but its not autocompleting, on mouse click it is, but when hover away, nothing, update as above

Comment: Can anyone please help?